# My jupyter notebook is notebook is not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

```
(base) C:\Users\deves>conda install jupyter nb_conda ipykernel
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```

### Package Plan

environment location: `C:\Users\deves\anaconda3`

added / updated specs:

- ipykernel
- jupyter
- nb_conda

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
  nb_conda           pkgs/main/win-64::nb_conda-2.2.1-py38_1
  nb_conda_kernels   pkgs/main/win-64::nb_conda_kernels-2.3.1-py38haa95532_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: - Enabling nb_conda_kernels...
CONDA_PREFIX: C:\Users\deves\anaconda3
Status: enabled

| Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `EnableNBExtensionApp`.
Enabling notebook extension nb_conda/main...
      - Validating: ok
Enabling tree extension nb_conda/tree...
      - Validating: ok
Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `EnableServerExtensionApp`.
Enabling: nb_conda
- Writing config: C:\Users\deves\anaconda3\etc\jupyter
    - Validating...
      nb_conda 2.2.1 ok

done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::nb_conda_kernels-2.3.1-py38haa95532_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::nb_conda_kernels-2.3.1-py38haa95532_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\deves\anaconda3\Scripts\.nb_conda_kernels-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
Enabling nb_conda_kernels...
CONDA_PREFIX: C:\Users\deves\anaconda3
Status: enabled
```

==> script output <==

```
stdout:
stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

return code: 1

()


(base) C:\Users\deves>

(base) C:\Users\deves>jupyter notebook
[C 12:05:35.041 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization: The 'kernel_spec_manager_class' trait of <notebook.notebookapp.NotebookApp object at 0x0000022CC9114F10> instance must be a type, but 'nb_conda_kernels.CondaKernelSpecManager' could not be imported.
```

Please help tried a lot by uninstalling and reinstalling, but that is not working.

Comment: https://github.com/Cadair/jupyter_environment_kernels/issues/33

Comment: chcp is a windows internal command. If it's not available in your path something's gone wrong.

Answer (score 4):

1. you should find the file `jupyter_config.json`, its path maybe like this 'C:\Users\mi.conda\envs\pytorch_1.7_cpu\etc\jupyter' then, remove the

   ```
    "kernel_spec_manager_class": "nb_conda_kernels.CondaKernelSpecManager"
   ```

   remove it including the above comma it there exists.
2. deleted the following three folders (you might want to make some backups though...)

   ~/.jupyter

   ~/.ipython

   ~/.local/share/jupyter

(here I deleted everything except for the "kernels" subfolder)

3. I ran the following 4 instructions:

   jupyter nbextension install --user --py widgetsnbextension

   jupyter nbextension install --user --py bqplot

   jupyter nbextension enable --user --py widgetsnbextension

   jupyter nbextension enable --user --py bqplot